# Floating Point Input

Tags: discussion

In this challenge: [rounding numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/166330/rounding-numbers/166337).

Most answers use floating point numbers, which means that many potential input values are impossible due to the limited precision.

For example, the inputs `.02675` and `4`. In this challenge, that would mean rounding `.02675` to `4` decimal places, which should result in `.0268`.
However, `0.02675` can't be represented exactly in the common floating point formats, and it's actually stored as `.02674999...`, which rounds to `.0267`.

Are these answers are invalid because they can't accept all the potential input values?

Comment: Possible [duplicate](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14407/71434), though a strong consensus wasn't reached there.

Answer (score 2):

#### Allow the default behavior

Floating point inaccuracies is a limitation we have to work with/around. That's just how computers work. If a language/program circumvents this and treats the numbers as accurate decimal numbers, then that's fine. If not, then that's fine too.

---

If a language/program **can** handle the numbers as accurate decimal numbers then allow this. That means that it's OK to return `0.15` as `0.2` if only one decimal number is required.

If a language/program **can't** handle the numbers as accurate decimal numbers, then allow for the default behavior. That means that it's OK to return `0.15` as `0.1` if only one decimal is required, since it's floating point value is `0.14999..`.

In the specific challenge you linked to, both `0.0268` and `0.0267` would be OK. However, rounding `0.25` to `0.2` would not be OK, since `0.25` can be accurately represented using floats.